# Why isn't my bot visible when I use webbrowser.visible = true

Tags: vbscript

I am new to VBScript and I wanted to write a basic bot to login to gmail to start to get a feel for this new language. I created a file called Chrome.vbs, and started to get to work. Here was my code:

```
set.webbrowser = createobject("internetexplorer.application")
webbrowser.statusbar = false
webbrowser.menubar = false
webbrowser.toolbar = false
webbrowser.visible = true
```

Once I wrote this code I tried to open the bot, but nothing appered. No window poped up and nothing activated, even though I used webbrowser.visible = true. If you can tell me what I did wrong I would be very greatful.

Comment: VBScript isn't a new language, in fact it is legacy by now. You probably meant new for you, but just to be clear. Also, IE is long deprecated. As for you code, there is a dot between set and webbrowser that should'nt be there.

Comment: Thank you for the advice and yes I ment new to the language

Comment: The "Invalid or unqualified reference" on line 1 is due to the period (**.**) after the word `set` in your first line.  Remove the period (.), save the script, then re-run it.  You should see Internet Explorer pop-up after that.  Hope this helps.